# How can I sort a list after group with rxjava?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am using RxJava 2 when I group a list by priority. Before I use groupBy, my list sort

HIGH - MEDIUM - LOW

but after I use gropBy, my list sort

HIGH - LOW - MEDIUM.

For example;

taskResults.add(new TaskResult(2,"Task2");

taskResults.add(new TaskResult(1,"Task1");

taskResults.add(new TaskResult(0,"Task0");

2 = HIGH, 1 = MEDIUM, 0 = LOW

```
    Observable.fromIterable(taskResults)
            .groupBy(TaskResult::getPriority)
            .flatMapSingle(Observable::toList)
            .subscribe(group -> {
                addItem(group.get(0).getPriority() != null ? group.get(0).getPriority().isEmpty() ? "No Priority" : group.get(0).getPriority() : "No Priority");
                for (TaskResult taskResult : group) {
                    addItem(taskResult);
                }
            })
```

but after I use gropBy, my list sort:

TASK2

TASK0

TASK 1.

---

**SOLVED**

As Rakeeb Rajbhandari said, I solved the problem. I used `concatMapSingle` instead of `flatMapSingle`.

Comment: using `concatMapSingle` instead of `flatpMapSingle` might help here, since concatMap respects queuing

Comment: concatMapSingle helped me. Thanks :)